# Filter pivot table on datetime index column

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas, filter, slice

Hi I want to slice a pivot table on specific dates and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates) where Orange1 gives an answer for columns with datetime values. To be complete here my data and my code:

```
Df_Pivot:

                                                    max
                                     DateTime_End
    DateTime_Start       Date                  
    2015-03-01 09:18:08  2015-03-01 2015-03-01 09:58:00
    2015-03-01 08:10:26  2015-03-01 2015-03-01 08:33:00
    2015-03-01 09:13:15  2015-03-01 2015-03-01 09:28:00
    2015-03-01 09:01:06  2015-03-01 2015-03-01 09:20:00
    2015-03-01 11:53:37  2015-03-01 2015-03-01 12:00:00
```

I would like to filter DateTime_Start on date. Now I have done this with the extra column date which is datetime.date() converted into string(I add the date column later). However, I think it is more elegant to filter the index column DateTime_Start only on the date.

Is this possible?

Inspired by [this Topic with the solution of Orange1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates), [this topic on datetime import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865143/descriptor-date-requires-a-datetime-datetime-object-but-received-a-unicode) and [this topic on too many indexers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781037/too-many-indexers-with-dataframe-loc), constructed this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.IndexSlice
data['Df_New'] = data['Df_Pivot'].loc[idx[date(year=2015,month=4,day=15),:],:]
```

It returns this:

```
   File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 1369, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: datetime.date(2015, 4, 15)
```

Comment: well, for the part of your data you show '2015-04-15' isn't there, only '2015-03-01'.  But the bigger problem may be that you are not taking a slice.  i.e. x:x is a slice, x is not.

Comment: Hi JohnE, you are right, it is example data, in the whole dataframe 2015-04-15 exists. Your comment got me thinking, you are right. I fixed it now with reindexing on only on DateTime_Start. Then you can simply slice by df[2015-04-15]. Thanks